# How to Plot pandas group by(sum ) data's based on the selection

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

[image]

I am trying to group by ID and sum of the groups and have to plot:

```py
grps = self.df_G_UI.groupby('Module')['#Runs','#Pass'].sum()
for name, grp in grps:
    if name == selectedMod:
        grp.plot(x=name, y=['#Runs','#Pass'], ax=self.a, kind='bar', color=['Blue', 'Green')
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What kind of plot are your expecting ? Also, could you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) ?

Comment: #grps=self.df_G_UI.groupby('Module')['#Runs','#Pass','#Fail'].sum().reset_index('Module')
            #for name, grp in grps:
            # if name == selectedMod:
            #         grp.plot(x=name, y=['#Runs','#Pass','#Fail'], ax=self.a, kind='bar',
            #